# How to count objects count that have ForeignKey relationship?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have two tables, lets say: Blogs and Posts. Posts have ForeignKey field which connects Blogs and Posts tables.

How can I count how many Blogs have at least 1 Post?

Answer (score 1):

Exclude blog that has no post, then count.

```
Blog.objects.exclude(post=None).count()
```

Comment: They are connected in reversed way - Post has `blog` field that is ForeinKey(Blog)

Comment: @dimazubrik, Django model creates reverse relation.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter by related model

```
 Blog.objects.filter(post__isnull=False).count()
```